is there a list of all possible capability.policy for security in firefox
in the about:config or user.js you can set some rules to change firefox advanced  settings
I'm interested capability.policy I'm trying to see if there is one specific rule i can change to all some websites to use the about:... protocol as a hyperlink
the capability.policy rules in something like this
 capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled
 // capability.policy.<policy name>.<capability>

but i can't find the name of the rule i want
i even tried to ask a question on stackoverflow about this topic (see: Firefox - Allowing about: protocol) but i didn't get any answers
then i tried to see if there is a complete list of all the posible values for capability.policy
in websites like admx.help and kb.mozillazine.org
but didn't find any list for it some useful examples but none answied my need
